# Is there, and if there is, what is the name of the concept that matter is made out of void/space?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, universe, space, matter

I can't recall where I heard about this, but it was rather intriguing. I recall the notion that matter is compressed void/space, where I remember an example of a bedsheet representing space, and the person describing the concept was making knots in the bedsheet and called it matter, and the pulling between knots was gravity.

I also remember at the end that person saying that the big bang would be the bedsheet stretching and if it unfolds the knots then its cold death of the universe, else, it contracts back like an elastic bedsheet which would be big crunch.

My own analogy was void/space being a sea of water and matter being pieces of ice but this is from a Dungeons and Dragons fantasy concept, the astral sea :)

Comment: That would be pretty close to a description of the standard model of high energy physics, although I have never heard this analogy and I don't think it's very good. The whole point of the real thing is that there is no such thing as void/empty space. It's quite the opposite: the vacuum is a highly complex object and there is nothing that is less than that.

Comment: Pardons, I have little knowledge of physics. Please excuse my poor choice of words.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't trying to scold you about the phrase, I am merely not familiar with this attempt at an explanation. Like I said, the correct explanation is, that there is no such thing as "nothing", "void" or even a "classical vacuum". We have known this for about a century, since it became clear, that the vacuum has, at the very least, a temperature and is filled, at the very least, with photons. It has snowballed from there since then, and now the vacuum is also filled with virtual particles and, particularly important, a Higgs component.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit in the spirit of [John Wheeler's geometrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrodynamics#Wheeler.27s_geometrodynamics).  He hoped to find in the dynamic geometry of GR a way for "mass without mass, charge without charge, field without field" to somehow emerge just from vacuum gravitational fields interacting. He contemplated "[geons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_%28physics%29)" which would be packets of gravitational waves held together on the short scale by the non-linearities of GR, which could appear as usual matter on longer scales.  It was an imaginative speculative idea, but it did not pan out as well as Wheeler hoped.

[Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) could also be related to your idea.  Kaluza postulated an extension of GR to 5 dimensions where the field solutions appeared to contain Maxwell's equations for electromagnetic fields as well.  Klein then noted that if this 5th dimension was small and curled up, these 'vacuum' solutions of GR would appear in a larger scale to just be electrodynamics.  An extra scalar field appears, that needs to be dealt with, but still this is an interesting idea.  This speculative idea still finds uses in modern unified theories.